# Xcodebuild can't find the correct scheme

Tags: xcodebuild

I'm trying to build an app using the commandline, however when I use xcodebuild -list it doesn't display the correct scheme, only those my project requires.

I have tried going into Xcode > Manage Schemes and set the correct scheme to "shared" but that doesn't help.

Using Xcode I have no problems building the main project but using Xcodebuild I can only build the dependencies.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
[image: Xcode]

[image: Console ouput]

Comment: Show a screenshot of your schemes in Xcode and the output from `xcodebuild -list`.

Comment: It doesn't need to be shared, but I cannot see what the problem is.

Comment: I got it working by recompiling the project with xcode again. Don't know what was wrong. Thanks for the help.